# Random CLR Exceptions while Debugging in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I keep getting random CLR exceptions while debugging which then causes the debugger to stop. It happens on my asp.net project and a blank asp.net project i created. Below is the error. Any ideas why? most of the time it happens while my app is idle or starting up

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0x71331c38, on     thread 0x1928. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

or sometimes i get this one

> System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled Message: An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in
>   Unknown Module.

**Update**
Im also having the same problem in VS2010 in a different project. They are both web based projects though. one is a set of WCF web services and the other is an asp.net mvc4 application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i found the cause of the problem. I also noticed a few Access Violation errors and i was wondering if its because i'm running it inside VirtualBox. Did a quick search on Visual Studio in Virtual Box and looks like the Access Violation error could be caused by VirtualBox. So i used Disk2VHD and setup Hyper-V. So far no issues. I suspect the other exceptions might have been caused by VirtualBox as well.